# HibernateTransactionManager transaction suspension support

Tags: hibernate, transactions

I wonder whether `HibernateTransactionManager` supports `Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED`
I've tried to simulate transaction timeout within such propagation, but still I have transaction timeout exception.

How can I ensure that within my code transaction is suspended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation enum javadoc: NOT_SUPPORTED -

> Actual transaction suspension will not work on out-of-the-box on all
>   transaction managers. This in particular applies to
>   JtaTransactionManager

So HibernateTransactionManager doesn't support transaction suspension, as jpa-counterpart does.